# Problem with Implicit conversion from Int to Ordered

Tags: scala

This is an implementation for a leftist heap in Scala.

```
package my.collections

sealed abstract class Heap[E](implicit val ordering:Ordering[E])  {

  import ordering._

  def empty: Heap[E] = Heap.empty

  def isEmpty: Boolean

  def insert(e: E): Heap[E]

  def merge(h: Heap[E]): Heap[E] = {
    def makeT(e:E,a:Heap[E],b:Heap[E]):Heap[E] = if (a.rank >= b.rank) Node(e,a,b,b.rank+1) else Node(e,b,a,a.rank+1)
    (this,h) match {
      case (Nil(),_) => h
      case (_,Nil()) => this
      case (Node(x,l1,r1,_),Node(y,l2,r2,_)) => if (x < y)  makeT(x,l1,r1.merge(h)) else makeT(y,l2,this.merge(r2))
    }
  }

  def findMin: E

  def deleteMin: Heap[E]

  protected def rank:Int
}


object Heap {

  private val emptyEl = new Nil[Nothing]

  def empty[E] = emptyEl.asInstanceOf[Heap[E]]

}

private case class Node[E](e: E, left: Heap[E], right: Heap[E], rank: Int)(implicit  ordering:Ordering[E]) extends Heap[E]()(ordering) {

  def deleteMin = left.merge(right)

  val findMin = e

  def insert(e: E):Heap[E] = Node(e,empty,empty,1).merge(this)

  def isEmpty = false

}

private case class Nil[E]()(implicit ordering:Ordering[E]) extends Heap[E]()(ordering) {

  def deleteMin = throw new NoSuchElementException

  def findMin = throw new NoSuchElementException

  def insert(e: E):Heap[E] = Node[E](e,Heap.empty,Heap.empty,1)

  def isEmpty = true

  protected def rank = 0
}

object PG {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val e:Heap[Int] = Heap.empty[Int]
    val e1:Heap[Int] = e insert 3
    val e2:Heap[Int] = e1 insert 5
    val e3:Heap[Int] = e2.deleteMin
    println()
  }
}
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to scala.math.Ordered
    at scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$3.compare(Ordering.scala:117)
    at scala.math.Ordering$class.lt(Ordering.scala:71)
    at scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$$anon$3.lt(Ordering.scala:117)
    at scala.math.Ordering$Ops.$less(Ordering.scala:100)
    at my.collections.Heap.merge(Heap.scala:27)
    at my.collections.Node.insert(Heap.scala:53)
    at my.collections.PG$.main(Heap.scala:77)
    at my.collections.PG.main(Heap.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
```

My questions are:

1. What exactly am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?
2. Is there a systematic way of understanding such errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are getting a class cast exception, i would look at possible wrong casts in your code. i can find one cast:

```
def empty[E] = emptyEl.asInstanceOf[Heap[E]]
```

and since `E` is not covariant, this is a cast error, `Heap[Nothing]` is not a subclass of `Heap[E]` !

You will have quite some job to make `E` covariant here, so unless you need this functionality, you may just fix the cast:

```
object Heap {
    def empty[E](implicit  ordering:Ordering[E]) = new Nil[E]
}
```

By the way, if `Heap` was covariant in `E` (e.g. `Heap[+E]`), you wouldn't need to do the cast, because scalac would accept that you return `Nil[Nothing]` for a `Heap[E]`. So unless you know exactly why you use `asInstanceOf` and there is no way around it, it is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: Just to complement this, it seems to me that the problem is that, by calling `Nil[Nothing]`, it is `Ordering[Nothing]` that gets passed on as implicit, and it is accepted elsewhere because of the `asInstanceOf` lie.

Comment: Of course you're right, and this is a complete idiot moment for me, but is this fixable so that there is only one instance of the empty node?

Comment: @user44242 Why do you want just one instance? As I said, you could try to make `Heap` covariant in `E`, then you could use `Nil[Nothing]`. Scala's `List` class is constructed that way, `Nil` is a case object.

Comment: It's extremely untrivial to make the heap covariant, since orderings are either invariant or contra-variant (scalaz). Nil is a case object since there are no invariant types involved. And the reason is very simple, there should be no need to have multiple copies of the empty object live at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is some more proof that my answer is correct.

```
class A[B](implicit ord: Ordering[B]) {
  def compare(x: B, y: B) = ord.lt(x, y)
}
object A {
  private val e = new A[Nothing] ()
  def empty[X] = e.asInstanceOf[A[X]]
}
val test = A.empty[Int] // works
test.compare(1, 2)      // ouch
```

You can see that it's perfectly valid to make a wrong cast **regarding type parameters**! This is part of the sad JVM story of **type erasure** -- since casting occurs at runtime, `A[B]` and `A[Nothing]` reduce to A[java.lang.Object] and hence the cast itself is not forbidden.

The truth (mistake) is just revealed at the later point...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most screwed up examples I have ever seen of what can go wrong when you lie to the compiler! :-)

I'll show what goes on line by line, so one can see what's going on (but 0__ is right and deserves the accepted answer).

```
val e:Heap[Int] = Heap.empty[Int]
```

That calls

```
def empty[E] = emptyEl.asInstanceOf[Heap[E]]
```

Which calls

```
private val emptyEl = new Nil[Nothing]
```

Which takes an implicit `Ordering[Nothing]`. I was very surprised there was such a thing, so I looked it up. One thing about `Ordering`, is that if your collection is `Ordered`, it will make an `Ordering` of it available. The method that provides this is:

```
implicit def ordered [A <: Ordered[A]]: Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A] {
    def compare(x: A, y: A) = x.compare(y)
}
```

So, here's the deal about `Nothing`: it is a subclass of everything. Ergo, it is a subclass of `Ordered[Nothing]`, thus `Ordering[Nothing]` is available.

Anyway, there's no error so far. The next line is:

```
val e1:Heap[Int] = e insert 3
```

This calls `insert` on `Nil`:

```
def insert(e: E):Heap[E] = Node[E](e,Heap.empty,Heap.empty,1)
```

Note that no `Ordering[E]` is being passed to method `insert`, so it is using the one passed to `Nil`, `Ordering[Nothing]`. Still no error, though, so next line:

```
 val e2:Heap[Int] = e1 insert 5
```

This calls `insert` on `Node`:

```
def insert(e: E):Heap[E] = Node(e,empty,empty,1).merge(this)
```

Again, no `Ordering[E]` was passed, so it uses the one it received on creation, still `Ordering[Nothing]`. This will finally cause the error, on this line of `merge`:

```
  case (Node(x,l1,r1,_),Node(y,l2,r2,_)) => if (x < y)  makeT(x,l1,r1.merge(h)) else makeT(y,l2,this.merge(r2))
```

The expression `x < y` is the problem. There's no `<` method defined on `x`, since `x` is just a generic `E`, so it goes through implicit conversion to execute it:

```
new ordering.Ops(x) < y
```

Where `Ops.<` is:

```
def <(rhs: T) = lt(lhs, rhs)
```

And `lt` is defined on `ordering` (which was imported). In other words, it executes this:

```
ordering.lt(x, y)
```

That will result in a call to `ordering.compare`. We saw the definition for `Ordering[Nothing]` previously, which was:

```
x.compare(y)
```

And here is where the error happens. The type of `x` is `java.lang.Integer` (because of auto-boxing). The method `compare` is from `scala.math.Ordered`, which `java.lang.Integer` obviously does not implement.

So it fails. All of this because of a little white lie... :-)

If, on the other hand, an `Ordering[Int]` was being used, it would resort to this definition:

```
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int) = 
      if (x < y) -1
      else if (x == y) 0
      else 1
  }
```

Here, `<` exists, because `x` is `Int`.